# .htaccess Reduce Spam

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, spam, socialengine

For reduce spam in wordpress comment i using below code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*domainname.com* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

My question is: I want to reduce spam in "**signup**". The url like this **http://www.domain.com/signup**

How to change this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*
```

Become **Signup** ???

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in .htaccess stops spam by saying:

When accessing the file wp-comments-post.php(which is the file that handles the posting of comments) and the visitor doesn't come from the yourdomain or the user agent of the browser is empty, we can block it.

The reason is that when somebody posts a comment, they have clicked on a button on your site and so the referrer is yourdomain.com

I'm assuming you don't really want this for the page signup as well. People could directly access that page and you want them to sign up.

To reduce spam in signup, it's better to know how the signup works. WordPress doesn't have a page signup, so I'm assuming you are using a 3rd party plugin for signup.

Comment: Yes, i'm not using Wordpress. I using 'socialengine' script.
In 1 day i got more than 100 spam :(


Can you help me to block spam using .htaccess, please!


Socialengine register url using like this: **http://www.domain.com/signup**

Comment: I don't know the script, so sorry

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to reduce automated spam signups is to use "honeypot" approach - hide one of required fields you have with styles (for example email) so visitors won't see it. Add additional field with some random name. Adjust SocialEngine signup to use new field instead of  email. In case hidden email field is filled with some data stop the registration - you got a bot.

(Our team has a simple SocialEngine4 plugin for that called Honeypot)